# How do I copy an app on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, ipados

I’m not asking about how to transfer an app, I’m wondering if I can copy an installed app on the iPad to create another, fresh version of the app on the same iPad.

Comment: As this is not possible maybe we can help if you explain your reason for wanting to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps do not side load on iPadOS / iOS so this isn’t a feasible option unless you care to jailbreak and disable sandbox restrictions.

The best you can do easily is have apps that support multiple launches, but the settings and sandboxes are shared and it’s up to the developer to program how you might use each “window” in a multitasked app differently than the other instances.

Answer (score 0):

So hey mate, I agree with bmike but here’s something you can try.

The first step is to download the .ipa file of the required app, you can just search the required app.ipa on the web and you can get many links for the same. After downloading the .ipa file, install Sideloadly (sadly Cydia Impactor doesn’t work anymore) on your PC or Mac. You can go through the formalities. Although there are no known problems, I suggest you use a less important AppleID to log in to Sideloadly.

Then connect your iPhone or iPad to the laptop, launch Sideloadly choose the required .ipa file, and download it to your phone. Now the app is downloaded but you can’t open it - so follow the below steps:

1. Open **Settings** and then open **General**
2. Scroll down below the VPN - you can see another option. Click on "Allow Access" and then you’re done.

You have the same app twice on your device.

Comment: Any doubts - pls let me know .

Comment: How do you sideload ?

Comment: There’s an program called sideloadly . You can download it from the web .